# stsm - Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Spring Thyme Seed Starter Manager (latest version) gives me a Whitelabel Error Page on http://localhost:8080/stsm. As this is an example application to demonstrate Thymeleaf 3.0, I'm disappointed it doesn't even display the initial web page. I am new to Java and the Spring Framework so I have no idea where this error comes from.

I have no errors in the application and it starts just fine in Eclipse.
I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3) with jdk-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin.exe installed. The JRE System Library is [JavaSE-1.6]

As a side note, this other Spring example runs perfectly:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The link to stsm is: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-stsm